# How to supress extra space after period in rmarkdown Latex?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I have .rmd file which I would like to compile to latex/pdf. That's the issue:

Latex puts more space after period characters such as "." or "?". Sometimes is not useful. I would like to *supress* this behavior in rmarkdown (knitr) files.

Consider this .rmd file:

```
---
output: pdf_document
---

Prof. Dr. hc. mult. now. ay. I. Ch. Weiss-Ois
```

I would expect less space after each period than is rendered.

I have tried these without success:

```
Prof. Dr.\ hc.\@ mult. now. ay. I. Ch. Weiss-Ois  
Prof. Dr.~hc.\@ mult. now. ay. I. Ch. Weiss-Ois
```

I have looked up [this link](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3641) where the Pandoc author replies to a similar question but it seems without solution.

Software used:

- R w/ RStudio
- pandoc
- R package rmarkdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure they don't work, or are the differences just too small to detect?  If I do the whole text this way, the cumulative difference is noticeable when comparing lines side by side:

```
Prof. Dr. hc. mult. now. ay. I. Ch. Weiss-Ois

Prof.\ Dr.\ hc.\ mult.\ now.\ ay.\ I.\ Ch.\ Weiss-Ois

\frenchspacing 
Prof. Dr. hc. mult. now. ay. I. Ch. Weiss-Ois
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandoc simply inserts non-breaking spaces after some abbreviations. They have, however, still the same width. Try e.g.

```
foo\hspace{.15em}bar
```

Comment: thanks; that works, and gives flexibility. At the same time, @DavidKlotz is right in saying that `\` does reduce the space *a little bit*.